# Cannot call function of a class from main

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
using namespace std; 

// my code starts

class Cat {
public:

int age;
string name, race, voice;
Cat(int age2,string name2,string race2,string voice2);
void PrintInformation();
};

Cat::Cat(int age2,string name2,string race2,string voice2) {
    age = age2;
    name = name2;
    race = race2;
    voice = voice2;
}

Cat::Meow(){
    cout << "Cat says: " << fluffy.Meow() << endl;
}


void Cat::PrintInformation() {
    cout << "Name: " << name;
    cout << "\nAge: " << age;
    cout << "\nRace: " << race << endl;

  }
// my code ends

int main() 
{ 
Cat fluffy(2, "Fluffy", "Bombay", "Meoow!!!"); 
fluffy.PrintInformation(); 
cout << "Cat says: " << fluffy.Meow(); 
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to make this code work. My main problems seems to be that i don't know how to call `fluffy.Meow();` from `int main()`.
Thanks, for any help!

Comment: You didn't declare `Meow()` in your class definition. It needs a return type too.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to **declare** `Cat::Meow` in the class declaration.

```
//some code
void PrintInformation();
void Meow();
```

Additionally, you have to specify what the return type of the function `Meow` is, in your case it would be `void`, because it returns nothing.

You also have some recursion going on, `Meow` calling `Meow` (forgetting about the fact that `fluffy` isn't a variable in this scope). Your `Cat` class knows nothing about the instance `fluffy`, so you can't access it.

I guess you meant `voice` instead.